# iPhone : upload image to web aspx file

Tags: iphone, forms, upload, asp.net, content-type

I have a little problem.
I have to upload a photo from my iPhone to a web server with POST Method but the server file is in aspx.
I tried my code with my server and PHP file : works well !
Now with aspx file : doesn't upload :(

I don't havec access to the .aspx .

Here is my iphone code :

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image,70);

NSString *urlString = @"http://iphone.domain.net/upload_photos.aspx";


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n",[c nom]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

I think the problem comes from the Content-Type or for my dataUsingEncoding: parameter.
Have you got and idea to solve it?

Comment: btw are you sure the aspx works in the first place, with the exact parameters you're passing here?

Comment: and could you specify what's in `[c nom]`?

Comment: [c nom] is juste an NSString to name my file "%@.jpg"
I have no idea for aspx file I can't take a look at it :(

Comment: I see that it is the filename ;-) just wondering what it is. If you put in some crap, things will break. (think newlines or quotes)

Comment: you can test the aspx by uploading something using the regular way, using a html form.

Comment: That's a good thing. Now hook up your favorite network analyzer, and see what's going on on the wire. You're on a mac? use `tcpdump -s 10240 -A port 80` in the terminal. Then observe what the form does, and compare it to what your app does in the simulator. (close any other page which may reload banners etc to get rid of the junk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not opposed to using a 3rd party library consider looking at ASIHttpRequest. It'll make your life so much easier:

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

```
  ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Upload a file on disk
    [request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg"
    forKey:@"photo"];

    // Upload an NSData instance
    [request setData:imageData withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but doesn't work :(
I wrote :


ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
 [request setData:imageData withFileName:@"myImage.png" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"photo"];

Comment: Do you actually send the request?

[request startSynchronous];

Comment: Yes. Problem solved, it was the compagny server which sucks -_-

Answer (score 0):

normally, the boundary does not contain the `---` when it's specified in the `Content-Type`. Apart from that, can't see anything unusual.

Comment: So I have to write this : NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"14737809831466499882746641449"]; ?

Comment: yes, or even `NSString *boundary = @"14737809831466499882746641449";`

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload it to the aspx server from the command line with [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html). Once you've got that working, pass `-v` (verbose) or `-i` (include HTTP headers) to check exactly what is being sent, and then you can try to replicate that in Cocoa.