# UIImage upload to jsp server

Tags: ios, jsp, upload, uiimage

I'm trying to upload a image file to server but it is not getting uploaded below i have added my code

```
imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToUpload, 0.9f);

NSString *urlString =@"http://sample.com/LargeUpload.jsp";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setTimeoutInterval:10];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data;filename=\"\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:YES error: nil ];
```

Comment: Congratulations, you broke SO's string syntax highlighting. edit: actually, it looks like this code doesn't compile.

Comment: @Pradu when it's not getting uploaded, what does server respond with? Any errors?

Comment: I'm getting no response from server..

Comment: Check out the related questions on the right hand side, for example this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366260/iphone-upload-image-to-web-aspx-file?rq=1

Comment: `sendSynchronousRequest: returningResponse:error:` [Returns nil if a connection could not be created or if the download fails](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Use `error:` parameter to get and analyze the error message (`NSError * err;`, `error:&err]`). Tell us the results. Also make sure you accept the answer to your previous question if it helped you.